# Multiple authors for an entry

Tags: sections, permissions, author

The website I'm currently working on is a plattform where several 'subgroups' can post events but also have their own subpage. So the two affected secrions are 'event' and 'subgroup'.
Currently, every subgroup has an account which is author of their entry and they can create new event entries (which are linked through an entry field).

I'm wondering if it's possible to have multiple accounts for a subgroup which have the permission to edit their entries but not the ones of other subgroups.

Long story short: is it somehow possible to assign an entry multiple authors?

Comment: Short answer: no every entry can only have one user asigned as an author. But you can customize the permissions and include custom permissions so your editors are only allowed to see and edit entries based on custom logic. That requires a plugin and PHP

Comment: @RobinSchambach ok, thanks. I may look into this ...

Answer (score 2):

We solved it like this...

We created a Users field called “Article Authors”, for that Articles section. And there unlimited users could be selected as “Authors” of the entry (for search results, relatedTo, etc...). Each article typically multiple authors.

But we assigned only 1 author as the only one with real editorial access, as the “owner”, so: basic Craft behavior.

We thought this would be limiting, but actually it turns out, in practice, it’s pretty good to have only 1 person in-charge with end-responsability. It’s clear where it lies, and he/she will communicate with the team before changing things. This: in contrast with 5 authors being able to acccess and edit an article, which we thought would be a good plan, but in reality isn’t. This forces them to communication amongst themselves and it’s clear who’s responsible.

Plus with the custom Users field, you basically maintain all functionality you want related to the entry.

We have about 250 articles now running with over +1500 author members, and have not got any complaints.

Comment: Thanks for the inights, but that won't work for us. I need a good alternative for people sharing accounts.

Answer (score 0):

[Robin's comment](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/30143/multiple-authors-for-an-entry#comment38725_30143) is correct, but I'll also add that https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/896 is a feature request to allow multiple authors on an entry that would address what you're looking for that you might want to subscribe to or add a comment to.